# How to access Letter Recognizer API in Android?

Tags: android, gesture-recognition, letter

I am creating a gesture application.
In the Gesture class docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/Gesture.html) it reads:

"A user-defined gesture can be recognized by a GestureLibrary and a
built-in alphabet gesture can be recognized by a *LetterRecognizer*."

So how do you use the LetterRecognizer and where is the docs on it?
There's no API for that in the docs, I've also searched android's code
itself, and besides the same comment above in the code there's
nothing.

I've implemented a letter recognizer manually by drawing the ABC
letters to a gesture raw file and using the regular
mLibrary.recognize(gesture) API, but the success rate is not very
high, not even close to Google's gesture search app.

Any help on this matter would be appreciated.
Thanks

****EDIT: Letter Recognizer is a future release. It is not yet available***

Comment: It looks like the bug in the documentation. I have posted an issue on the Android bug tracker for this, let's see if someone comment/fix it: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16637

Comment: Please let me know if you receive a response about it. Thanks

Comment: Ok. I'll post news here if any

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would look at the code on this page:

http://www.anddev.org/gesture_recognizer_and_character_recognition-t2998.html

He says the source code for his character recognizer is in the SVN, too.  You might find some helpful tidbits.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I looked into this code and found that he was using a hashmap to recognize the gestures. I would have assumed he might have used a gesture library for recognition purposes. His recognizer isnt fully operational either, some bugs still remain. At least some insight into the letter recognizer! Thanks!

Comment: Just wanted to say that this link triggers a Bitdefender Trojan warning.