# Compare a drawing to letters

Tags: android

I'm allowing a user to draw on a canvas. Once tapped OK, I want to compare the drawing with one or more letters (could be double byte). How do I best map the drawing to the letter sequence?
I need an approach for scaling, comparing and visualizing. For the later I though to use a 3 color approach: mapping pixels black, letter only pixels green, drawing only pixels red. Would that work?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're looking for [OCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition).  Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106202/android-ocr) for some prebuilt solutions.

OR!  Maybe you'd like to use the [built-in gesture recognition API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843136/how-to-access-letter-recognizer-api-in-android) to guess those letters instead of rolling your own implementation.

Comment: Agreed. Using gesture to track the movements is probably the best way to go. Faster and possibly more accurate than OCR it afterwards. User experience might be better too because you can do it in real time.

Comment: Actually NO. I'm not looking for OCR. OCR is: take a graphic and show what letter matches best. What I need is: I know the target letter upfront and want to get a score how well it did match. It is a language / writing learning game.

Comment: Ah, that would have been useful to know in the original question.  Good luck!